# Pause command not working in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, servicenow

I am trying to run a test (on ServiceNow platform) using Selenium IDE. In order to execute background scripts I put some sleep time using pause() command. But it's not working. Please find screen shot for reference.

[Test Case screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7oIi.png)

Comment: nothing on the screenshot indicates pause is not working...

Comment: Screenshot was just for reference to the code. The problem lies with command. Control does not stop at pause.

Comment: The way pause works it wouldn't stop at the pause step, in the IDE window you should see the pause step turn green, and the following step will stay as yellow for the duration of your pause. Can you confirm if this is what's happening? Or is it instantly executing the following step as well?

Comment: Thanks Smith. That helped me.